# Guy gets isekaied into fantasy world, and is the first human to discover magic in the world as a child

Tags: story-identification, anime

Anime, Tv-Series with Japanese style animation.
Found it on Tiktok, and watched a few episodes but forgot to save the name for later.

It was fairly modern, not new as in this season but, i'm guessing its from 2020 or so.

The genre are (and im just guessing here) Adventure, isekai, adventure, action. Probably got some more but I don't remember.

He gets isekaied and is born as a young (lord's?) boy, don't remember if he was ever a baby, maybe a small time skip?. He has a somewhat rich family with land to manage, that his father manages, not a big house, very small house, with walls or a fence.

The boy has a sister, that is close to the same age as him. She showed him a lake close by, and in the lake are fish. At night they glow and small glowing orbs emerge from the lake.
The boy gets fascinated by this, and asked his dad if magic is a thing, but his father said "magic?" as in there is no such thing as magic in this world.

He gets somewhat depressed or let down, sulking that there's no magic in this world.
Long story short he remembered the fish, startes studying them and came to the conclusion that they are using magic.

He then goes on to discover magic through science, using tools to be able to use magic.

Example, I think he needed to use some kind of gloves to use lightning magic, and a flint to use fire magic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, what colour was the boy's hair?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I dont really remember his hair colour to be exact but im guessing it was dark or brown, but i want to say his sister's hair is blond, could be wrong and just mixing anime here.

Comment: Why do i remember watching this as an anime.

Comment: @fampy - Probably because someone made a motion comic out of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're describing [*Magic Maker: How To Create Magic In Another World*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/157056/Magic_Maker__Isekai_Mahou_no_Tsukurikata) (AKA *Magic Maker: Isekai Mahou no Tsukurikata*) but that isn't an anime as far as I'm aware. It was a manga and light novel adaptation.

[image]

Our hero is isekai'd into the family of a local noble. He becomes very depressed when he discovers that magic isn't a thing in this world. His sister shows him a lake with glowing orbs and he goes on to research magic, eventually learning how to control it.

[image]

---

[image]